# Setting focus in ASP

Tags: javascript

I’m maintaining a site in ASP, one of the tasks is to set the focus on textbox on a page. 
Here is what I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.psForm['password'].focus();
//AND
document.getElementById("password").focus();
-->
</script>
```

I didn't think this would work... and it doesn't:

```
<form id="psForm" action="logonpw.asp" method="post" defaultfocus="password">
```

This doesn't work:

```
<body onload="javascript:docuument.psForm.password.focus();">
```

Here is the form:

```
<form id="psForm" action="logonpw.asp" method="post">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td>
          Password:
       </td>
    <td>
      <input type="password" name="password" value="<%= password %>" size="50">
        </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

Comment: There is a typo in your body onload version

Comment: retagged, the fact that it is ASP is irrelevant

Comment: BTW, you don't need to wrap your JavaScript in comments: <!--
 --> single only browsers born before 1997 will display your code instead of running it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:
Add:

```
id="password"
```

to the input tag, then use:

```
document.getElementById("password").focus();
```

Answer (score 2):

a)  move

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.psForm['password'].focus();
//AND
document.getElementById("password").focus();
-->
</script>
```

to bottom of page source.

b) fire code on load

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function handleOnLoad(){
document.psForm['password'].focus();
//AND
document.getElementById("password").focus();
}
-->
</script>
...
<body onload="handleOnLoad();">
```

and by the way, only the second onfocus would do any good.

Comment: I still had to add an ID="password"
Since the body tag is in an include, I now have an error on every other page. Maybe that will help convince the project manager rewrite this app.
Combined with Bravax answer I have a workable solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Greg. :) I should have elborated more like you did.

nitroxdm why are you getting an error on every other page? 
You could add a javascript function call  to the onload event using JQuery, for example, just for that one page. Thus not effecting the others.

Comment: Yeppy.. I missed that.  The JQuery solution mentioned "$(document).ready(function(){  // Your code here... });" will wait for the entire DOM to be loaded, which prevents problems but may give a perceivable delay in firing.

Answer (score 1):

```
<body onload="javascript:docuument.psForm.password.focus();">
```

should be

```
<body onload="javascript:document.psForm.password.focus();">
```

Check spelling...

Comment: Thanks for catching that, but it didn’t help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body onload="javascript:document.psForm.password.focus();">
```

document was misspelled

Comment: Thanks for catching that, but it didn’t help.